# Designing a restful URI for ternary relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, resources, uri

I'm working on a Rails project which is going to expose a set of resources through URIs. The problem I have is as follows:

Consider these models, Student, Note, and Lesson. Each Lesson can have many notes which is posted by Students. In Active Record's literature:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lesson
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now I want to know the URI design and resource design to support following scenario:

> retrieve list of all notes which is posted by student with id 5 on
>   lesson with id 4.

Please note that if I define resources in routes.rb like this:

```
resources :lessons do
  resources :notes
end

resources :students do
  resources :notes
end
```

then I can access notes through "/lessons/4/notes/" and "/students/5/notes" but what about the query I explained earlier?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
/notes?lesson=4&student=5
```

This is a URI the will probably only be used with `GET`. So it is a perfectly valid URI that identifies the Resource you want: The list of all notes that are meeting certain conditions.

**Note:** REST URIs should not be limited by what the used framework supports.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am going to use this URI to **POST** data as well. So I assume that I should use http headers to **POST** the data, or should I use the same format i.e. "/notes?lesson=4&student=5" to post as well.

Comment: Don't post to an URI like this. The query parameters `lesson` and `student` should be read as parameters of a search: give me all notes for a lessen and a student. If you want to add or change notes, lessons, or students, do this with `POST` or `PUT` against the proper URIs.